# Populating field with sequential timestamp in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes, time-series

I have a point layer in a GeoPackage with this attribute table.

```
name  id             timestamp
   A   1   23:03:2022T23:30:00
   A   2
   A   3
 ...
   B   1   23:03:2022T23:30:00
   B   2
   B   3
 ...
```

What I need is populate the timestamp column adding 5 seconds to the previous value grouped by `"name"` column and ordered by `"id"`.

Is there a way to do this using the Field Calculator? I am messing around field calculator but I'm stuck.

Comment: Does `id` start from 1 and continue sequentially for each `name`? Is this a shapefile (means timestamp is string) or a geopackage( or any format) accepting datetime field?

Comment: Yes, it is a geopackage layer and the timestamp column datetime type. I already edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your data are structured strictly like your example, you can do this (which returns a datetime object):

```
with_variable('start_time', to_datetime('23:03:2022T23:30:00', 'dd:MM:yyyyTHH:mm:ss'),

    CASE 
        WHEN 
            "id" = 1
        THEN 
            @start_time
        ELSE 
            @start_time + to_interval(to_string(("id"-1) * 5) || ' seconds')   -- add an interval of the elapsed seconds according to the `id` field
    END

)
```

[image]

To return a string:

```
with_variable('form', 'dd:MM:yyyyTHH:mm:ss',    -- make a variable of the format to avoid redundancy
    with_variable('start_time', to_datetime('23:03:2022T23:30:00', @form),

        CASE 
            WHEN 
                "id" = 1
            THEN
                format_date(@start_time, @form)
            ELSE
                format_date(@start_time + to_interval(to_string(("id"-1) * 5) || ' seconds'), @form)                
        END

    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is based on "time `23:03:2022T23:30:00`". What if the first time values are different or unknown. I guess `23:03:2022T23:30:00` is just an example. Somehow, you need to group by name and get the starting time for each name.

Comment: Hence my remark *If your data are structured strictly like your example, you can do this*

Comment: It would be great, if you could add a general solution for that kind of issues.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I will take another look when I have some more time to add a more generalised expression

Answer (score 5):

If the first time values are different or unknowns (as mentioned in the comment by @Kadir Şahbaz), use this expression:

```
array_max (
    array_agg( 
        timestamp,
        group_by:=name
    )
) + to_interval ( to_string (id*5-5)  ||  ' seconds' )
```

Explanation: with `array_agg()`, you collect all timestamp values from each `name` group in an array. Take the maximum value (if all other values are `NULL` as here, otherwise depending on what kind of dattime values you have in this field).

[image]

Comment: Nice solution to make it dynamic. Though you will need to use `to_string (id*5-5)` else you add an extra 5 seconds. Where `id`=1, you actually want to add 0, `id`=2, add 5, etc.

Comment: Indeed,thanks for pointing me to that. Changed my soultion accordingly.